# I am receiving an error which says column "address" can not be null

Tags: java, mysql, sql, struts2, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to run a query but whenever I run I get an error saying that "column address cannot be null".

here is my code.

```java
package com.rajesh.action;
import java.sql.*;
public class AccountDao {


public static int  save(Actionraju r){
int status =0;
Connection con=GetCon.getCon();
PreparedStatement ps;
try {
ps = con.prepareStatement("Insert into account (accountno, username, password,   repassword, amount, address, phone) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

ps.setInt(1,r.getAccountno()); 
ps.setString(2,r.getUsername());
ps.setString(3,r.getPassword());
ps.setString(4,r.getRepassword());
ps.setDouble(5,r.getAmount());
ps.setString(6,r.getAddress1());
ps.setDouble(7,r.getPhone());
status=ps.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();}
return status;

}

}
```

my Actionraju.java looks like this.

```java
package com.rajesh.action;
public class Actionraju  {
private int accountno;

private String username;
private String password;
private String repassword;
private Double amount;
private String address;
private Double phone;



public int getAccountno() {
return accountno;
}


public void setAccountno(int accountno) {
this.accountno = accountno;
}


public Double getAmount() {
return amount;
}


public void setAmount(Double amount) {
this.amount = amount;
}


public Double getPhone() {
return phone;
}


public void setPhone(Double phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}


public String getUsername() {
return username;
}


public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}


public String getPassword() {
return password;
}


public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}


public String getRepassword() {
return repassword;
}


public void setRepassword(String repassword) {
this.repassword = repassword;
}




public String getAddress() {
return address;
}


public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}


public String execute(){

int i = AccountDao.save(this);
if(i>0){
return "success";
}
return "error";

}

}
```

In my mysql database I have 7 columns, namely "accountno", "username", "password", repassword", "amount", "address", "phone". For all these 7 columns I checked "not null" box and here my "accountno" is the primary key.

please anyone help me out of this. I am a newbie.

Comment: the error suggests that you are inserting a null value for the address column. try to print out your address value to check.

Comment: are you sure`r.getAddress1()` is not null?

Comment: yes,I have checked all "Not null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have enough information to be sure we're helping you.  But here's some things you can do to debug.  Do a `System.out.println(r.getAddress1())`.  If it prints null, that's your problem.  The way you created your table says address can't be null, but you're passing in a null value in your code.  Either make the table less restrictive, or make sure you pass in a value.

Also, change your insert sql so it says something like this:  `Insert into account (accountno, username, ...) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)` That way, you know you're setting the correct column for the address field.  Perhaps you *think* that 6 means the address field, but it's really using 2 for the address field.  If you write your sql to include the column names, you can be sure you're doing what you intend to be doing.

Comment: Now it is giving me java.lang.NullPointerException. Do not know what I am doing.

Comment: @Rajesh Show us your new code in your original question and show us the whole error for the NullPointerException.

Comment: yes, take a bow Mr. tieTYT, you have explained to me like my primary teacher so that i was able to understand what I am doing wrong. Now I am able to insert all the values but address value is showing null, why it is so even after i am entering some values in address field?

Comment: did i hurt you? I am sorry, I didnt mean anything bad to you. :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the r.getAddress1() is null, try passing a constant string in:
`ps.setString(6,r.getAddress1());`

Try changing it to:

```
ps.setString(6,"SOME ADDRESS");
```

and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: cool... so its clear that your r object is not having any value in the address feild and is passing a null.

Comment: you can either populate some value in the r object or set the address value to a blank string. something like: if(r.getAddress1()==null){ps.setString(6,"");} else{ps.setString(6, r.getAddress1());}

Comment: found out an error..in my jsp page I was giving name "adddresss" instead of "address". now i fixed it so my problem is solved..thank you yash for trying to help me....loads of love...

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
ps.setString(6,r.getAddress1());
```

with

```
ps.setString(6,r.getAddress());
```

then its works....

Comment: I have done that ramesh, but still it is showing null. DO not know what is going wrong.

Comment: Oh, everything is perfect, and its executed correctly, no error is given to me here,,@Rajesh.

Comment: then why it is acting like that with me?

Comment: before insert just print every value with "System.out.println();" then check for its corresponding field's size, type and etc. then insert.

if you still get same error again,,
then give the static values like "ps.setString(6,"SOME ADDRESS");"
for every one .if you success in this case then trace out the error in type casting..

Comment: i checked but address shows 0 but rest all are taking values.

Comment: please check the code where the (Actionraju class) object is initialized.

i mean "r.setAddress("Address_content"); " in your ( business logic ) code. @ Raj

Comment: found out an error..in my jsp page I was giving name "adddresss" instead of "address". now i fixed it so my problem is solved..thank you yash for trying to help me....loads of love... –